# How can I change strapi entries with HTTP requests?

Tags: strapi

I want to make a leaderboard, so I need to change or delete entries from my game. In strapi admin panel in "roles & permissions" is written, that Update is "PUT" and Destroy is "DELETE" Http request.

[Strapi admin panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfDhN.png)

When I send PUT/DELETE requests, strapi returns 404 error. Only POST and GET request works. I use Postman.
Сan you explain how to change strapi database entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to send the ID in the PUT/Delete request:

PUT http://localhost:1337/snlbs/1234